# git need of automated merging strategy

Tags: git

I have a master branch which is the production code. I have 3 teams branching out of it. One is doing bugfix, another one small enhancement and there is one more team for doing full development. So I have 3 branches bugfix,enhancement and develop.
Once Bugfix is tested it is merged with master and the updated master branch code has to reflect to the sub branches enhancement and develop. How to achieve this via automation. I don't want a person doing merge manually.

Comment: And what should the automation do when a merge conflict occurs?

Comment: Merging in Git _can't_ be fully automated because conflicts do occur. Somebody needs to roll up their sleeves and deal with that when it happens. (And even when no conflicts occur, somebody should be reviewing the merged code. You should run your tests against it. A clean merge doesn't guarantee that the code even compiles, let alone that it does what it's supposed to do.)

Comment: You need a build server (like jenkis) doing the merges (or even better rebases) only bothering a real person when a conflicht happend.

Comment: The bugfix branch  code will be branched out by developers ,after development completed it is  reviewed by reviewers and later  merged to bugfix branch which would be tested in atleast one lower environment..then only it's moved to master branch. So this merge can never introduce compilation errors...@Timothy.. I tried in Jenkins plugin to do merge from bugfix to master, but the merged code is present in local and doesn't get pushed to remote